# add item into add cart

Tags: php

I'm trying to add product into add cart. Please tell me what is the best way.
My mess code is.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    echo "IF part";
     $_SESSION['id'] = $_SESSION['id'] + $_SESSION['id'];
     $k = $_SESSION['id'];
    // store session data
$_SESSION[$k]['product_name']=$_REQUEST['product_name_value'];
$_SESSION[$k]['product_price']=$_REQUEST['product_price_value'];
$_SESSION[$k]['shop_name']=$_REQUEST['shop_name_value'];
$_SESSION[$k]['Quantity']=$_REQUEST['selquantity'];
$_SESSION[$k]['color']=$_REQUEST['txtcolor'];
$_SESSION[$k]['Size']=$_REQUEST['selsize'];
$_SESSION[$k]['Product_Type']=$_REQUEST['selproducttype'];
$_SESSION[$k]['Remarks']=$_REQUEST['Remarks'];
$_SESSION[$k]['final_price']=$_REQUEST['final_price_value'];
$_SESSION[$k]['txturl']=$_REQUEST['txturl'];

}else {
    echo "else part";
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
    // store session data
    $_SESSION[$k]['product_name']=$_REQUEST['product_name_value'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['product_price']=$_REQUEST['product_price_value'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['shop_name']=$_REQUEST['shop_name_value'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['Quantity']=$_REQUEST['selquantity'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['color']=$_REQUEST['txtcolor'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['Size']=$_REQUEST['selsize'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['Product_Type']=$_REQUEST['selproducttype'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['Remarks']=$_REQUEST['Remarks'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['final_price']=$_REQUEST['final_price_value'];
    $_SESSION[$k]['txturl']=$_REQUEST['txturl'];
}
```

I'm trying to add these product details into array.
thanks

Comment: You know `$_REQUEST` can contain data from `GET`, `POST` and `Cookies` right?

Comment: I hope you're aware of the possible dangers as well? Also, in this example someone can easily modify the `final_prize` to shop for cheap or free.

Comment: Since you're taking the `final_prize` out of the request anyone could submit to your page with a modified `final_prize` in either the query string, or form-fields. Or even a Cookie since you're using `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: @Htbaa thanks for reply. how to prevent this kind of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't repeat yourself ;) means if you have two lines of code that are identical check if you really need to write it twice!

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
  // create cart
  $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}

// create item
$item = array();

// fill item

$item['product_name']=$_REQUEST['product_name_value'];
$item['product_price']=$_REQUEST['product_price_value'];
$item['shop_name']=$_REQUEST['shop_name_value'];
$item['Quantity']=$_REQUEST['selquantity'];
$item['color']=$_REQUEST['txtcolor'];
$item['Size']=$_REQUEST['selsize'];
$item['Product_Type']=$_REQUEST['selproducttype'];
$item['Remarks']=$_REQUEST['Remarks'];
$item['final_price']=$_REQUEST['final_price_value'];
$item['txturl']=$_REQUEST['txturl'];

// add item to cart

$_SESSION['cart'][] = $item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first do some factorization on your code with creating a function to add the data to the `$_SESSION`.

Then, it's impossible to give you an answer, there's no "best way", there's only a way that suits your need and you're the only one which can find it.

Answer (score 0):

See below.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ordertb (time, cust_id, prod_id, quantity, pmt_mode, city, delivery_state,amtval) VALUES ( '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$idval1."','".$item["product_code"]."','".$item["qty"]."','".$_SESSION['spmt1']."','".$_SESSION['scity']."','1','".$item["subtotal"]."')";
```